# Customize header for coordinates in CSV export

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to customize the header for csv export from QGIS?

I use "Export -> Save Features as" to create a csv with the names and coordinates for a list of points.
The default when choosing Geometry AS_XYZ is "X,Y,Z,name" - would it be possible to get "easting,northing,elevation,name" instead?

Comment: Either run `refactor fields` after export (don't know if it works with `.csv`, you'll have to try), or attach these values via the field calculator before export.